# Spring jms activemq

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I use activemq and spring jms. I have a problem.

This is my EmailSender

```
@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:/properties/dev/application.properties")
public class EmailSenderImpl implements EmailSender {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailSenderImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void sendEmail(final Users user, EmailCauses emailCause) {
        LOGGER.debug("Sending email to user with id {} with cause {}", user.getId(), emailCause);

        //Retrieve User profile which defined with lazy fetch type.
        //It prevents org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException in jms message receiver method
        user.getUserProfile();

        jmsTemplate.send(env.getProperty(emailCause.getEmailQueueName()),
                new MessageCreator () {

                    @Override
                    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                        return session.createObjectMessage(user);
                    }
                }
        );  
    }
```

This is my EmailHandler.

```
@Service
public class EmailHandler {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailHandler.class);

    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;
    private MessageSource messageSource;


    @Autowired
    public EmailHandler (JavaMailSender mailSender, VelocityEngine velocityEngine, MessageSource messageSource) {

        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.velocityEngine = velocityEngine;
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }


    //TODO - refactor method, add reserve server
    @Transactional
    public void processEmailNotifications (Users user) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        LOGGER.debug("Preparing to send greeting email to user {}", user);

        UserProfiles userProfile = user.getUserProfile();

        Map <String, Object> model = new HashMap <> ();
        model.put("name", userProfile.getName());
        model.put("patronymic", userProfile.getPatronymic());
        model.put("token", UriUtils.encode(user.getConfirmationToken(), "UTF8"));

        String email = user.getUserProfile().getEmail();
        sendEmail(email, "email.wellcome.subject", model, "wellcome_email.vm");

    }
     private void sendEmail (String emailTo, String subjectMessage, Map<String, Object> model, String templateName) {
        LOGGER.debug("Sending email to {} with subject message {}", emailTo, subjectMessage);

        try {

            MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper (message, true, "UTF-8");

            helper.setTo(emailTo);
            helper.setSubject(messageSource.getMessage(subjectMessage, null, Locale.getDefault()));

            String emailText = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, templateName, "UTF-8", model);
            helper.setText(emailText, true);

            mailSender.send(message);
            LOGGER.info("Email to address {} with subject {} was sent successfully", emailTo, subjectMessage);

        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            LOGGER.error("Email to address {} was not sent", emailTo, me);

        }

    }
```

There is following log in my stack trace. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

> o.s.jms.core.JmsTemplate - Executing callback on JMS Session:
>   ActiveMQSession
>   {id=ID:igor-Aspire-5820TG-33061-1474030841626-1:7:1,started=false}
>   2016-09-16 16:02:40.871 - [http-bio-8080-exec-6] [DEBUG]
>   o.s.jms.core.JmsTemplate - Sending created message:
>   ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false,
>   messageId = null, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId =
>   null, producerId = null, destination = null, transactionId = null,
>   expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0,
>   brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent =
>   false, type = null, priority = 0, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0,
>   targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content =
>   null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null,
>   redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties
>   = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, text = xDDD}

Answer (score 0):

Can you post other logs and JmsTemplate setup config because the session is not started on your logs and producer, messageid and destination... infos are null